# How to make PIVOT(Crosstab) in html and php

Tags: php, html, mysql

It will be such a great help for me if anyone can solve this.
I have a MySql Database tables which has a records of:

```
student_id    subject_id    scores
s01           eng01         10.00
s01           math01        10.00
s01           science01     10.00
s01           physic01      10.00
s02           eng01         20.00
s02           math01        20.00
s02           science01     20.00
s02           physic01      20.00
```

Which I want to display in html and php in a way like this

```
student    eng01    math01    science01    physic01
s01        10       10        10           10
s02        20       20        20           20
```

I've done different sets of sql queries as well as php codes but I can't still get through it. Help will be so much appreciated

Comment: Related: [SQL Query: Rows to Columns Pivot into PHP Array / HTML Output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15028124/2943403) and [Pivot dynamic html table using mysql and php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14492552/2943403) and [pivot html table using php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21345762/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know all the subject names in advance, you can create a pivot table using `CASE` expressions:

```
SELECT student_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN subject_id = 'eng01' THEN scores ELSE 0 END) AS eng01,
    MAX(CASE WHEN subject_id = 'math01' THEN scores ELSE 0 END) AS math01,
    MAX(CASE WHEN subject_id = 'science01' THEN scores ELSE 0 END) AS science01,
    MAX(CASE WHEN subject_id = 'physic01' THEN scores ELSE 0 END) AS physic01
FROM students
GROUP BY student_id
```

Output (for your sample data)

```
student_id  eng01   math01  science01   physic01
s01         10      10      10          10
s02         20      20      20          20
```

If you don't know all the subject names, you could use this query to get a list:

```
SELECT DISTINCT subject_id FROM students
```

Then in PHP you could create a loop to build the query from the results of this one, something along the lines of (assuming you have the result of that query in a variable called `$result`) this. Note that this code also saves the subject names for later use to output a heading row for a table.

```
$sql = 'SELECT student_id';
$headings = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
   $sql .= ", MAX(CASE WHEN subject_id = '{$row['subject_id']}' THEN scores ELSE 0 END) AS {$row['subject_id']}";
   $headings[] = $row['subject_id'];
}
$sql .= ' FROM students GROUP BY student_id';
// run query
```

To output this data into a HTML table, you could use code something like this. Again I'm assuming the output of the query is in `$result`:

```
echo "<table>\n<thead><tr><th>Student ID</th><th>" . implode('</th><th>', $headings) . "</th></tr></thead>\n<tbody>";
while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    echo "<tr><td>{$row['student_id']}</td>";
    foreach ($headings as $h) {
        echo "<td>{$row[$h]}</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</tbody></table>\n";
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I've done this in query but I am more likely to display the output via web :( In html by the way.

Comment: @MarkC you need to be more clear in your question exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: Can you please show he how to show the records in HTML table?