# Create a 'pivot' table from array

Tags: php, arrays, html-table

I have an array that looks like this:

```
Array (
    Array ( [date] => 04/2021 [name] => Fred [value] => 12.00 )
    Array ( [date] => 04/2021 [name] => Tom [value] => 160.00 )
    Array ( [date] => 04/2021 [name] => Mike [value] => 9.00 )
    Array ( [date] => 07/2021 [name] => Tony [value] => 200.00 )
    Array ( [date] => 07/2021 [name] => Fred [value] => 43.00 )
    Array ( [date] => 07/2021 [name] => Tom [value] => 114.00 )
    Array ( [date] => 07/2021 [name] => Mike [value] => 28.00 )
)
```

I am trying to get the data into a simple HTML table where the name goes on the x axis, the date on the y axis and the values where they intersect.

For example:

```
          Fred     Tom     Mike    Tony
04/2021   12.00    160.00  9.00    0
07/2021   43.00    114.00  28.00   200.00
```

I do not know if I am over thinking this but I cannot get this to work - I can get the x axis to work by pulling out the unique values for name but then when it comes to the y axis and the intersections I cannot get the data to display how I need.

I either end up with repetition of columns or a single column and so on. This is where I have gotten up to but still scratching my head how to do this:

```
<?php
$unique_names = array_unique(array_map(function($elem){
    return $elem['name'];
}, $data));
?>

<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <?php foreach ($unique_names as $i) { ?>
            <th><?php print $i;?></th>
        <?php } ?>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<?php
foreach ($data as $row) {
    for ($i=0; $i<=count($unique_names);$i++) {
        if ($i==0) {
            print "<tr><td>".$row['date']."<td>";
        } else {
            print "<td>".$row['value']."<td>";
        }

        if ($i==count($unique_dates)) {
            print "</tr>";
        }
    }
}
?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: The next time you ask such a question, please post the sample data as either a `var_export` or JSON - then we can use it via copy&paste directly, without having to modify it first.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63810788/2943403

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, reorganize your data into an array that uses the date as key on the first level, and the name on the second. Collect the names at the same time:

```
$input = [
    ['date' => '04/2021', 'name' => 'Fred', 'value' => '12.00'],
    ['date' => '04/2021', 'name' => 'Tom', 'value' => '160.00'],
    ['date' => '04/2021', 'name' => 'Mike', 'value' => '9.00'],
    ['date' => '07/2021', 'name' => 'Tony', 'value' => '200.00'],
    ['date' => '07/2021', 'name' => 'Fred', 'value' => '43.00'],
    ['date' => '07/2021', 'name' => 'Tom', 'value' => '114.00'],
    ['date' => '07/2021', 'name' => 'Mike', 'value' => '28.00'],
];

$data = $names = [];

foreach($input as $item) {
    $data[$item['date']][$item['name']] = $item['value'];
    $names[] = $item['name'];
}
$names = array_unique($names);
```

Then create your table. Loop over the names to create the header row first.
Then loop over the reorganized data array (to create one row for each date), and inside that loop over your names again - if you find an entry matching the name in the data array, then output the value, otherwise nothing.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <?php foreach($names as $name): ?>
        <th><?php echo $name; ?></th>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach($data as $date => $userData): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $date; ?></td>
        <?php foreach($names as $name): ?>
        <td><?php echo $userData[$name]??'-'; ?></td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Result:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
                <th>Fred</th>
                <th>Tom</th>
                <th>Mike</th>
                <th>Tony</th>
            </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>04/2021</td>
                <td>12.00</td>
                <td>160.00</td>
                <td>9.00</td>
                <td>-</td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>07/2021</td>
                <td>43.00</td>
                <td>114.00</td>
                <td>28.00</td>
                <td>200.00</td>
            </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked great - FYI for anyone using < PHP 7.0 $userData[$name]?? did not work for me but I just had to change it to use $userData[$name]?$userData[$name]?'-';

Comment: @CBroe You can skip the `array_unique()` call if you assign the `name` value as the key when you populate `$names` in the loop.

Comment: @bhttoan  No, a falsey ternary expression does not do what CBroe's null coalescing operator will do.  You will need to use `isset($userData[$name]) ? $userData[$name] : '-';` because this will appropriately handle cases where variable is undeclared.  (This prevents Notices being generated -- more professional coding)

Comment: Sorry typo my side, that is what I used!

Answer (score 1):

> Here is your answer, great exercise.
> [image]

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
    </head>
    <body>
<?php
$data = Array (
    Array ( 'date' => '04/2021' ,'name' => 'Fred' ,'value' => '12.00' ),
    Array ( 'date' => '04/2021' ,'name' => 'Tom' ,'value' => '160.00' ),
    Array ( 'date' => '04/2021' ,'name' => 'Mike', 'value' => '9.00' ),
    Array ( 'date' => '07/2021' ,'name' => 'Tony' ,'value' => '200.00' ),
    Array ( 'date' => '07/2021' ,'name' => 'Fred' ,'value' => '43.00' ),
    Array ( 'date' => '07/2021' ,'name' => 'Tom' ,'value' => '114.00' ),
    Array ( 'date' => '07/2021' ,'name' => 'Mike' ,'value' => '28.00' )
);
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $tmp[$value['name']][$value['date']] = $value;
}

$unique_names = array_unique(array_map(function($elem){
    return $elem['name'];
}, $data));
$unique_dates = array_unique(array_map(function($elem){
    return $elem['date'];
}, $data));

?>
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Dates</th>
        <?php foreach ($unique_names as $i) { ?>
            <th><?php print $i;?></th>
        <?php } ?>
    </tr>
</thead>
<?php
foreach ($unique_dates as $date)
{   
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$date."</td>";
    foreach ($unique_names as $name) {
        if(array_key_exists($date,$tmp[$name]))
        echo "<td>".$tmp[$name][$date]['value']."</td>";
        else
        echo "<td>0</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
<tbody>

</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please always include a plain English explanation with every answer.  Volunteer contributors should endeavour to be more than snippet dumpers -- answers should intend to educate and empower not only the OP but thousands of future researchers

Comment: It is not advantageous to store the whole row of data in `$value` when your html markup generating script only ever uses `value` from the row.  Also, `$unique_names = array_keys($tmp);`  is much simpler than `array_unique(array_map())` -- but the truth is that you do not need  it to be declared anyhow.